# How to put controllers and factories in separate files

Tags: angularjs

I have one module 'app' and I am trying to separate it's controllers and one factory into individual files. The app works when I chain all controllers in the main app.js file. It breaks instantly when I try to move them to new files.

I've tried everything to get my controllers/factories in a separate file but I constantly get this error:

> [$controller:ctrlreg] The controller with the name 'AppCtrl' is not registered.
>   https://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.2/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=AppCtrl

I have declared the scripts in the main html file.. All of the js files are in the same directory. I am attempting to add the controller using `angular.module('app)` as the reference to the main module, but nothing works.

My directory structure:

> |app
>
> > > | app.js
> > >       | AppCtrl.js
>
> |public
>
> > > |index.html

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

angular.module('app')
  .config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        template: require('./home.html'),
        controller: 'AppCtrl'
      })
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  });
```

AppCtrl.js

```
angular.module('app')
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $route) {
//controller code
});
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="app" lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>

  <script src="../app/app.js"></script>
  <script src="../app/AppCtrl.js"></script>


  <base href="/">
</head>
```

Am I missing a step on getting these separated out?

Comment: Have you double checked that AppCtrl.js is actually loading in dev tools network? The basics of what you have shown look right apart from no angular.js tag but we know that has to be included also for the internal error to show

Comment: You're missing `)` at the end of `AppCtrl.js` - Is this syntax error exist in your actual code too?

Comment: @AlonEitan That was just a mistake in copying it over. I do have it correctly in the actual code. Edited it into my post.

Comment: @charlietfl I am new to all of this. Where would I check to see if it is loaded in dev tools network? Also what is the 'angular.js' tag? Is that this: import angular from 'angular'; because I just left that out of the code snippet.

Comment: Same console you see errors in , apart from the console tab...there are other tabs like elements and network etc. The network tb shows all requests made by page

Comment: @charlietfl Found the network tools. Looks like it isn't loading because I am getting 404 not found

Comment: So it is a path problem to that file. Double check file name vs what is in script tag also

Comment: @charlietfl I can't seem to get the path to work. I've confirmed the file names are correct. How would you load the scripts based on the file structure in my post?

Comment: Same way you are currently doing. Should also be able to open that path in browser address bar. A js file will show up as just text. Perhaps you have a server config issue but that doesn't seem right if you can load app.js from same directory. Might try renaming as all lowercase file name and same in script tag

Comment: Man I'm sorry to be a pain. This still doesn't work. I renamed the file to appController. I've opened the path in my browser and it works just fine, but trying to import it still gets a 404. I am actually getting the 404 for both app.js and appController.js 

Request URL: http://localhost:8080/app/app.js
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Comment: Copy the absolute path from address bar where you can see the file in to the script tags. Perhaps you need to put it all in `public` . don't know enough about your server config